# codeforces exercise 71A "Way Too Long Words"

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>

int count(char str[100])
{
    int i = 0;
    while (str[i] != 0)
    {
        i++;
    }
    return i;
}

int main() {
    char palv[100] = "vinirj";
    int i = (count(palv) - 2);
    int m = count(palv);
  
    scanf("%d", &n);
  
    if (m <= n && m >= 1)
    {
        printf("%s", palv);
    }
    else
    {
        printf("%c", palv[0]);
        printf("%d", i);
        printf("%c", palv[m - 1]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I was trying to solve the problem *"Way Too Long Words" exercise 71A* and managed to solve it at least in my personal compiler poi when I submit it on the codeforces page directly in the compiler of the wrong answer page it itself, I experienced the sample inputs given by the exercise and give exactly the same output request. Where did I go wrong?

Comment: The details of [the actual codeforces question](https://codeforces.com/problemset/problem/71/A) should be provided [in your post](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/74354266/edit), along with your actual attempt at solving the problem. Obviously the code shown here won't do it; you never read any words from stdin, nor count any characters of said same.

Comment: Is there a special reason why you can't just use `strlen` and come up with a poorer implementation?

Comment: `char str[100]` in a parameter list means exactly the same thing as `char *str`. It's a feature/quirk of C.

Answer (score 0):

> I experienced the sample inputs given by the exercise and give exactly the same output request.

The [Codeforces problem statement](https://codeforces.com/problemset/problem/71/A) says the program is to read input in which the first line contains a number indicating the number of lines that follow and then the following lines contain the words to be processed.

The code in the question does not read such input. It reads a number but uses it to compare with the length of a string, and then it does not read anything else from input. To work, the program must be rewritten to read input as stated by the problem statement.

It is not possible that the program shown in the question read the sample inputs given for the exercise and produced the required outputs. If you mean you tested the sample code by modifying it to contain the sample inputs, one at a time, then that is inadequate for the exercise. You must write new code to read input. If you mean you have some program intended to solve the exercise but showed only a reduced sample in the question, then you should edit the question to show the actual program.